# SQL UPDATE rows from related TOP 1 records

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a table `Products` with 2 columns: `ProductID, ProductName`.

When I sell those products, I store the sale in 2 tables:

- `SalesHeaders` with 3 columns: `IDHeader, EmployeeName, Date`
- `SalesRows` with 3 columns: `IDHeader, IDRow, ProductID`

There are 2 employees, John and Mary.

Now I need to add a new column in my table `Products` called `LastMarySaleDate`. So I want to update `Products.LastMarySaleDate` and for that I need to select the most recent record from `SalesHeaders` where `EmployeeName = 'mary'` and `SalesRows.ProductID = Products.ProductID`.

Here are sample data with the expected results

Products (before UPDATE):

```
ProductID  ProductName  LastMarySaleDate
--------- ------------  ----------------
A01        Mouse
A02        Keyboard
A03        Speakers
```

SalesHeaders:

```
IDHeader  EmployeeName  Date
--------  ------------  ----------
1         Mary          2020-05-01
2         Mary          2020-05-02
3         John          2020-05-03
```

SalesRows:

```
IDHeader  IDRow  ProductID
--------  -----  ---------
1         1      A01
1         2      A02
2         3      A01
3         4      A02
3         5      A03
```

Products (after UPDATE):

```
ProductID  ProductName  LastMarySaleDate
--------- ------------  ----------------
A01        Mouse        2020-05-02
A02        Keyboard     2020-05-01
A03        Speakers     Note: Empty, since Mary never sold this productID
```

I've tried

```
UPDATE Products
SET Products.LastMarySaleDate = H.Date
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM SalesHeaders 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesRows ON SalesHeaders.IDHeader = SalesRows.IDHeader
     WHERE SalesHeaders.EmployeeName = 'Mary' 
       AND SalesRows.ProductID = Products.ProductID
     ORDER BY SalesHeaders.Date DESC) AS H
```

but I can't figure it out. If anyone could help me with this it would be great, thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: @GMB thank you for your interest :) I've added some data and the result i expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE #Product (ProductID varchar(10),   ProductName varchar(20),  LastMarySaleDate DATE)
INSERT INTO #Product
    VALUES ('A01','Mouse', NULL),
    ('A02','Keyboard',NULL),
    ('A03','Speakers',NULL)


CREATE TABLE #SalesHeader(IDHeader INT,  EmployeeName varchar(20), DT  Date)
INSERT INTO #SalesHeader VALUES (1,'Mary','2020-05-01'),
                                (2,'Mary','2020-05-02'),
                                (3,'John','2020-05-03')


CREATE TABLE #SalesRows(IDHeader int,  IDRow int,  ProductID varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #SalesRows VALUES(1,1,'A01'),
                            (1,2,'A02'),
                            (2,3,'A01'),
                            (3,4,'A02'),
                            (3,5,'A03')



UPDATE #Product
    SET LastMarySaleDate = t2.DT
FROM #Product t1
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ProductID, MAX(dt) DT 
        FROM #SalesHeader t1
        INNER JOIN #SalesRows t2 on t1.IDHeader = t2.IDHeader
        WHERE t1.EmployeeName = 'Mary'
        GROUP BY ProductID
    ) t2 on t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
```